# How will I convert this int into a string in an if statement?

Tags: python, string, int

I am making a simple text based game and have gotten an error.  I have to convert the int in my code into a str.  My code looks like this:

```
tax1 = input("You May Now Tax Your City.  Will You? ")
        if tax1 == "Yes" or tax1 == "yes":
            tax2 = input("How Much Will You Tax Per Person In Dollars? ")
            if tax2 > 3:
                print("You Taxed To High!  People Are Moving Out")
                time.sleep(1.5)
                population -= (random.randint(2, 4))
                print("The Population Is Now " + str(population))
                time.sleep(1.5)
                money += (population * 2)
                print("From The Rent You Now Have $" + str(money) + " In Total.")
            if tax2 < 3:
                print("You Have Placed A Tax That Citizens Are Fine With.")
                time.sleep(1.5)
                money += (tax2+(population * 2))
                print("From The Rent And Tax You Now Have $" + str(money) + " In Total")
```

What will I add to my code to do this?

Comment: Please post the error and stack trace. Just telling us you got an error doesn't help.

Comment: For reference, you probably want to use `if tax1.lower() == "yes"` instead of `if tax1 == "Yes" or tax1 == "yes"` - it's a bit simpler to read and gives the user more options (any combination of caps and lowercase).

Comment: You have to take care of a city okay that is why there is tax!

Comment: @thegrinner wasn't talking about why there is tax—the comment was about clarifying your code. Is the issue with `str(money)`, or `str(population)`? What's the actual error you're getting? Have you looked at the values that `population` and `money` have at the time when you call the `str()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

```
tax2 = int( input("How Much Will You Tax Per Person In Dollars? ") )
```

If you're sure the input won't contain decimals.  If you're not sure, and want to keep the decimal value, you could use:

```
tax2 = float( input("How Much Will You Tax Per Person In Dollars? ") )
```

Or use integers, but play it safe, with

```
taxf = round( float( input("How Much Will You Tax Per Person In Dollars? ") ) )
tax2 = int( taxf )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if int(tax2) > 3:
```

Because `input` returns you a string, so you should parse an int from it.

Also note that if the player inputs *not a number* your game will crash.

*And just in case you are using Python 2 (as opposed to Python 3) you should go with `input_raw` instead of `input` as the latter will also evaluate given string as Python code and you don't want this*.

Comment: It's [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), not `input_raw`. You might also want to include the reasons for using it instead (ie `input()` will evaluate user supplied Python).

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a *string* (In Python 3), which obviously can't be used for mathematical expressions (as you have tried).

Use the built-in [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function. It converts an object to an integer (If possible, otherwise it would give a `ValueError`).

```
tax2 = int(input("How Much Will You Tax Per Person In Dollars? "))
# tax2 is now 3 (for example) instead of '3'.
```

However, if you are using Python 2.x, `int()` is not needed if you are using [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input), because (as shown in the docs) it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. However, if you want to input a string, you would want to input it like `"this"`.